# How to alight two textviews in a relativelayout

Tags: android-layout, android

I am playing around with a listview with two text views. It looks very bad at the moment.

[image]

I would like the text (Eight, Five ,etc) to begin some margin on the left. More importantly I want the Numbers on the right to be aligned with the text on the left. which is in the center.

What is the best way to align both the items in one line with some gap in the middle. Right now the text on the right is in top right.

This is my layout.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/num_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingTop="15dip"
    android:paddingBottom="15dip"
    android:paddingLeft="0dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/num_count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="#9ed321"
    android:paddingRight="13dip"
    android:paddingLeft="13dip"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cat_id"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Comment: what is the parent layout you're using?? it's better to have linear LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

Have a `LinearLayout` which is horizontal. Have the two in  `TextViews` inside it with  equal `0.5` weight. Keep both left aligned. You may have the left_margin on the whole Layout.

```
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:margin_left="10dp"
     >

    <TextView
         android:weight = "0.5"

    />

    <TextView
        android:weight = "0.5"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

P.S: I am just showing the concept. You may complete the layout as you desire.

Comment: oh.....I was under the impression that linearlayout can't be used when there are multiple items in the layout...I'll give it a try.

Comment: @birdy Yes, you can. Did it help eventually?

Answer (score 0):

To add a margin to the left use this in the XML file :

```
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
```

You can use the following to centre the TextView :

```
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

To add the Count to the right of the name :

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/num_name"
```

I hope that helps.

Both LinearLayour or RelativeLayout can be used within the list.

Comment: Also change android:layout_width="fill_parent" to android:layout_width="wrap_content" for the left TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out..

It will work. I have tried this in my project.

```
 <RelativeLayout
   <TextView
android:id="@+id/num_name"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="16dip"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:paddingTop="15dip"
android:paddingBottom="15dip"
android:paddingLeft="0dip"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/num_count"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/num_name"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:background="#9ed321"
android:paddingRight="13dip"
android:paddingLeft="13dip"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cat_id"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have changed the layout_width from "fill_parent" to "wrap_content"

Give it a try. If it is still not working, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
      <TextView
    android:id="@+id/num_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:text="fgth"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/num_count"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:background="#9ed321"
   android:gravity="right"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```